# "Reading" the information from picture in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to develop code to read out positional data from a picture thats been loaded into the program.

F.E. : Imagine a picture with houses (red squares) connected with lines.
Now what i would need are the posotions of the houses and the lines in such a way that i can use that data and do more with it. 
So : - Load Jpg (f.e) into the programm
     - Read the picture and save postions
     - Be able to work with the saved positional data.

My issue is that i struggle to find the right way to google this. Is it's as difficult as machine learing or is there a more simple way to solve this?
No need to get it explained, but more a place where i can start research this myself would be awesome!

Comment: I hope my answer will help you, that I'm wrong and that something, please leave me a comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find contours, you will be interested in [Hough Transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). Check the image on the bottom.

I recommeng getting a hang on OpenCV image processing library (more specifically the [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is a C# wrapper of OpenCV). It has a fairly big community and it's a project working for ages.

Generally `contour recognition` and `line recognition algorithm` are a good shot. You could add `opencv` to the search phrase.

If you want to detect lines, [Canny edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) would be a nice shot. Once again I recommend OpenCV for this task.